# Define a method that is a closure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, closures

I'm re-defining a method in an object in ruby and I need the new method to be a closure. For example:

```
def mess_it_up(o)
  x = "blah blah"

  def o.to_s
    puts x  # Wrong! x doesn't exists here, a method is not a closure
  end
end
```

Now if I define a Proc, it is a closure:

```
def mess_it_up(o)
  x = "blah blah"

  xp = Proc.new {||
    puts x  # This works
  end

  # but how do I set it to o.to_s.

  def o.to_s
    xp.call  # same problem as before
  end
end
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works (tested in irb):

**NOTE: This changes only `str` - not all instances of String. Read below for details as to why this works**

```
another_str = "please don't change me!"
str =         "ha, try to change my to_s! hahaha!"
proc = Proc.new { "take that, Mr. str!" }

singleton_class = class << str; self; end

singleton_class.send(:define_method, :to_s) do
  proc.call
end

puts str.to_s         #=> "take that, Mr. str!"
puts another_str.to_s #=> "please don't change me!"

# What! We called String#define_method, right?

puts String           #=>  String
puts singleton_class  #=>  #<Class:#<String:0x3c788a0>>

# ... nope! singleton_class is *not* String
# Keep reading if you're curious :)
```

This works because you are opening str's [singleton class](http://www.contextualdevelopment.com/articles/2008/ruby-singleton) and defining a method there. Because this, as well as the call to [Module#define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001654), have what some call a "flat scope", you're able to access variables that would be out of scope if you used `def to_s; 'whatever'; end`.

You may want to check out some of these other "metaprogramming spells" here:

[media.pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/spells.pdf](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/spells.pdf)

**Why does it only change `str`?**

Because Ruby has a couple interesting tricks up it's sleeves. In the Ruby object model, a method invocation results in the reciever searching not only it's class (and *it's* ancestors), but also it's singleton class (or as Matz would call it, it's eigenclass). This singleton class is what allows you to [re]define a method for a single object. These methods are called "singleton methods". In the example above, we are doing just that - defining a singleton method name `to_s`. It's functionaly identical to this:

```
def str.to_s
  ...
end
```

The only difference is that we get to use a closure when calling `Module#define_method`, whereas `def` is a keyword, which results in a change of scope.

**Why can't it be simpler?**

Well, the good news is that you're programming in Ruby, so feel free to go crazy:

```
class Object
  def define_method(name, &block)
    singleton = class << self; self; end
    singleton.send(:define_method, name) { |*args| block.call(*args) }
  end
end


str = 'test'
str.define_method(:to_s) { "hello" }
str.define_method(:bark) { "woof!" }
str.define_method(:yell) { "AAAH!" }

puts str.to_s #=> hello
puts str.bark #=> woof!
puts str.yell #=> AAAH!
```

**And, if you're curious...**

You know class methods? Or, in some languages, we'd call them static methods? Well, those don't *really* exist in Ruby. In Ruby, class methods are really just methods defined in the Class object's singleton class.

If that all sounds crazy, take a look at the links I provided above. A lot of Ruby's power can only be tapped into if you know how to metaprogram - in which case you'll really want to know about singleton classes/methods, and more generally, the Ruby object model.

HTH

-Charles

Comment: But I need to modify it only in one object, not in all (in the class).

Comment: That's what this does. Each object has what's called a singleton class - it's own personal class for storing methods. Test it out - you'll see that other instances of String are unaffected. I'll update my answer with a test, to show that it works.

Comment: "it's" is only used when you mean "it is". Replace "it's" with "its" in your answer. Aside from that, good work ;)

Comment: @banister: D'oh - thanks! I hate when people mix up "your" and "you're", etc... I'll leave it as is as a reminder that I'm not perfect :)

Answer (score 10):

[Feature #1082](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1082) implemented in Ruby 1.9.2 makes this an easy task with [Object#define_singleton_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001040):

```
def mess_it_up(o)
  x = "blah blah"

  # Use Object#define_singleton_method to redefine `to_s'
  o.define_singleton_method(:to_s) { x }
end
```

The concepts involved are still the same as in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495550/define-a-method-that-is-a-closure-in-ruby/2495650#2495650), which provides a more in-depth description of how this works in Ruby's object model, as well as a `Object#define_method` definition that is conceptually the same as Ruby 1.9.2's `Object#define_singleton_method`.

Other methods that you might find useful for similar tasks:

- [Object#singleton_class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001013)
- [Object#singleton_methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001026)
- [Object#respond_to_missing?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001006) (great blog post [here](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html))

Comment: I've had to use this, when I wanted to create an instance method that customizes an object by adding calls to the creating instance's methods: `class A; def foo(b); puts "fooing #{b}"; end; def agument(b); b.define_singleton_class(:foo) { foo(self); }; end; end`. This obviously doesn't work, because there is no magic way to reference the `self` that was in closure's scope. The solution was to take a page out of Javascript's book and do something weird like: `myself = self` and then use `myself` in the singleton method to call the parent. Sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
class Foo
  def mess_it_up(o)
    x = "blah blah"

    o.instance_variable_set :@to_s_proc, Proc.new { puts x }
    def o.to_s
      @to_s_proc.call
    end
  end
end

var = Object.new
Foo.new.mess_it_up(var)

var.to_s
```

The problem is that code in `def` is not evaluated until it's run, and in a new scope.  So you have to save the block to an instance variable on the object first and retieve it later.

And `define_method` doesn't work because it's a class method, meaning you would have to call it on the class of your object, giving that code to ALL instances of that class, and not just this instance.

Comment: No, you'd use `Module#define_method` on the object's singleton class - in which case ONLY that one object is changed. Run the example in my answer if you doubt me :)

Comment: Yep your answer is better.  I forgot about the singleton class.