# Other ways to "embed" or make variable "static" in new method?

Tags: ruby, closures

Is there any other ways to make it another way than with closure and define_method?

Say i have this:

```
def test
  result=[1,2,3]
  metadata=['foo', 'bar'] # for simplicity, could be fetched from database
  result.define_singleton_method :headers, lambda { metadata }
  result
end
```

I'm curious, are there other ways to embed, make static or well, "copy" metadata variable into method in Ruby?

Comment: Can you add some more code describing what you want? Show how it'd differ from something without embedding.

Comment: What about subclassing Array or writing class including Enumerable module if you need simple iteration functionality?

Comment: Andrew: because scope is different, so metadata variable isn't defined when f.e. defining like in Matherus Moreira answer or defining closure in body of def, and call test.headers

Comment: @IvanStana Can you please provide a more detailed code sample explaining what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it kind of iffy to be defining methods like this (probably you should have an object that looks like an array rather than making the array look like your object), but this will work as well.

```
def test
  result=[1,2,3]
  result.instance_eval { @headers = ['foo', 'bar'] }
  result.define_singleton_method(:headers) { @headers }
  result
end
```

You could also do something like this (it's a little different in that it creates a setter as well).

```
module HasHeaders
  attr_accessor :headers
end

def test
  result = [1,2,3].extend HasHeaders
  result.headers = ['foo', 'bar']
  result
end
```

Comment: Instance variables....very good idea, for me is better to have Array with results of query (from database) and method that returns metadata, than some custom class

Answer (score 0):

Well, method definitions aren't closures, so this will not work:

```
def result.headers
  metadata
end
```

Since you are testing, I recommend stubbing the method. With [`RSpec::Mocks`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames):

```
result.stub(:headers).and_return metadata
```

Related:

- [Define a method that is a closure in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2495550/512904)